# What is the meaning of the veiled woman with the hawk?

Tags: plot-explanation, secret-things

In the opening scene of [*Secret Things* (2002)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0287963/?ref_=nv_sr_1), and again three times throughout the movie, including the climax scene at the end, a veiled woman is seen, holding a hawk.  Sometimes the hawk is seen moving about as well, most notably at the end when it begins pecking at the corpse of Cristophe.

What is the significance of this woman and the hawk? What does it represent?